# Code igniter url rewrite on EC2

Tags: linux, apache, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a set of Codeigniter website hosted on
http://ec2-23-22-24-128.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

However, when it fails when I try to access via the sub-domain:

http://ec2-23-22-24-128.compute-1.amazonaws.com/dashboard

http://ec2-23-22-24-128.compute-1.amazonaws.com/index.php/dashboard

I have set the htaccess and set `AllowOverride All`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Could anyone advice?

Comment: Looks like you grabbed that rewrite from wordpress? Just keep it simply and copy directly from ci's guide

Comment: It works fine on Localhost WAMP. Now it show blank on all other pages

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the Codeigniter guide:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/urls.html

It clearly shows you that you can use this for `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: `not working still` is not descriptive at all.  This above is the rewrite that CI recommends, it works for me and many others. You need to debug your entry, make sure `mod_rewrite` is enable on your server.